# How to skip a line from an infile

Tags: file-io, load-data-infile

I have this code that allows the user to load an input file (option 1), display the contents of the input file (option2) and they have the option to exit (option 3). Is there any way that I can skip the first line of the input file from being couted?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{ char selection = ' ';
  char fileName[25];
  ifstream file;
  string line;

cout<< "Choose an action"<<endl;
string myMenu[3]={" 1 - Load An Exam ", " 2 - Display Exam ", " 3 - Quit " };
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
            {   cout<<myMenu[i]<<endl;}
            cin>>selection;

    switch(selection)   

{
    case '1': 
    cout<<"Please enter  the file name"<<endl;
    cin>>fileName,25;
    file.open(fileName);

    if (file.fail())
    {cout<<"Unable to open file"<<endl; 
     cout<<"Please enter the file name"<<endl;
    cin>>fileName,25;
    file.open(fileName); }



     break;

    case '2':
    if (file.good())
    { 
     while (getline(file, line))
    {cout<<line<<"\n";}
        file.close();
    }
    else cout<<"Unable to open file";
    break;   
    case '3':
        cout<<"Thank you!"<<endl;
    break;

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just continue inside the while loop. This will re-trigger the getLine function, which will move the pointer forward 1 line.

```
while (getline(file, line))
{
    if ( skipLineCondition ) { continue; }

    cout<<line<<"\n";
}
```

Also, please try to post better formatted code. We are here to help, but you should focus more effort into making it easy for everyone to help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, and yes I will try and do better, I have only posted twice on here before so I am still learning, I appreciate the help!

Comment: I also need to work on documenting my work better, I will definitely be mindful of that next time I post here :)

Comment: no problem. Did my answer help you? If so, you can mark it as an answer :)